# Why does this function give rise to an infinite loop?

Tags: list, haskell, recursion

I am trying to solve the exercises from the Haskell course I found online and for [this question](https://github.com/NICTA/course/blob/master/src/Course/List.hs#L287), I have the following implementation:

```
reverse ::
  List a
  -> List a
reverse Nil = Nil
reverse (x :. xs) = let l = (reverse xs) in l ++ (x:.Nil)
```

With `List` being defined as:

```
data List t =
  Nil
  | t :. List t
  deriving (Eq, Ord)
```

It seems that there is a infinite loop inside this function. But I could not find out why. Could you enlighten me?

Comment: Looks fine. Are you calling it with a infinite list perhaps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a correct implementation of `reverse` for the definition of `List` in your exercise book. If there is an infinite loop somewhere it is probably in your implementation of `(++)`.